# How does a CPU calculate on a hardware level?

Tags: cpu

I understand that a CPU operates on a FDE cycle and that there are various registers and counters that data gets moved between. I also appreciate that this data moves between memory and the CPU along the data busses.

However, what I cannot understand, is how does a CPU actually obey commands, fetch a specific piece of data and then perform an operation on it.

Please could you explain how this works on a hardware level. Perhaps even just something as adding two variables together.

This would be appreciated greatly as it is something that I simply cannot get my head round and my research has turned up nothing!

Comment: You might enjoy the book [The Elements of Computing Systems](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/elements-computing-systems).  It takes you from basic computer logic through a working computer, from the ground up.  The book's web site has simulation tools that allow you to create and simulate everything from the basic logic elements, to the CPU, to a simple compiler.  By the time you're done, you'll understand how a basic CPU works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CPUs are basically a massive network of transistors, various combinations of which represent logic gates.  Unlike analog transistors, digital transistors in CPUs and such are either on (1) or off (0).

Logic gates have inputs (1 or 2 - A/B) and an output.  Gates perform an operation on the inputs.  Some types of logic gates are as follows:

[image]

What exactly the gates are doesn't matter, just the function they perform.  They could be physical switches, discrete transistors, multiple gates on a DIP package, deposits on silicon, etc.

You can connect gates to each other to do more complicated things.  For example, with two gates you can make a 1-bit adder:

[image]

You probably want to add more than one bit, but you really need a "three bit" adder that supports a "carry in":

[image]

so now you can connect the "carry out" of one adder to the "carry in" of another.

[image]

The simplest way to "see" the output of your adders is to connect the output lines to an LED lamp or light bulb.  The simplest way to control the input of your adders is through a physical switch.  Sort of how the old Altair's control panel worked (though of course the Altair's control panel is connected to the full CPU and not just a simple adder):

[image]

So this is an example of how adding works.  A real modern CPU has billions of logic gates and has much more complex networks of them, but the basic operations above are the same.

[This](http://logic.ly/) is a good Windows/Mac program if you want to play around with logic gates in real time.  It also has an online version.

EDIT: Read [this](http://cpuville.com/ALU.htm) too.

Comment: This helps with understanding the calculation part, how about data retrieval and knowing which operation to perform in the first place?

Comment: @JamesHughes - What you just asked fills two 16 week college courses.  You do realize that right?  In simplest terms the instructions are decoded. Data Retrieval itself would be simply be a specific instruction

Comment: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-9/decoder/

Comment: Just like the adder above is "triggered" when something appears on the inputs, the decoder could "trigger" other circuits whose purpose is to execute the instructions (ADD, etc.) to run through selecting a signal.  The input of the decoder would in simple cases come from another circuit whose purpose is to talk to RAM.  Talking to RAM is similar to implementing a communications protocol.  Of course modern CPUs are much, much more complicated than that.  And I could be totally wrong.  Try electronics.stackexchange.com for people who might know what they are actually talking about.  :)

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question, something I'm curious in learning more about myself. From what I can tell so far:

- The control unit generates the signal with the instruction
- The arithmetic logic unit executes the signal with the instruction
- The registers store the signal with the instruction for later retrieval

I think these links might help explain more in case I didn't answer your question the way you wanted.

https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/10_Slides_CPU_buses.pdf

http://www.teach-ict.com/gcse_computing/ocr/212_computing_hardware/cpu/miniweb/pg3.htm